# (website data exchange || communication between sites) via php

Tags: php, web, communication

Is there any way to send simple string

from **websiteA.com -to-> websiteB.com** with php?

Where **websiteB.com "listens"(as not knowing the existence of websiteA.com)** any incoming simple strings sent and receives it?

Comment: You mean simple http requests?

Answer (score 2):

1. Setup a script on **websiteB** that handles a POST request (e.g. a string).
2. Use cURL or sockets on **websiteA** to send POST data (e.g. a string) to **websiteB**

Answer (score 0):

Very very simple vay is to use "rest api" - eg. create PHP file, which will recieve string and process it , and return XML / JSON ... or other formatted ( or unformatted ) answer. Client site ( eg. A ) just need to fopen ( or send request using cURL ) this php file with approtiate string

More complex way is to use SOAP - it have standart object in PHP , but it is reccomed to write wsdl file, which is a bit complex. see google for details